# updating a field status in DB table using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to update the 'not yet' status to 'already'

**Have error**

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'sudah' in 'field list'
UPDATE `tb_peserta` SET `sudah` = '' WHERE `no_pendaftaran` = '13'
Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 691
```

**My Controller**

```
function status_verifikasi($no_pendaftaran){
    $where = array('no_pendaftaran' => $no_pendaftaran);
    $this->M_pendaftar->status_verifikasi($where,'tb_peserta');
    redirect('admin/Ca_pendaftar');}
```

**My Model**

```
function status_verifikasi($where,$tb_peserta){
    if ($status_verifikasi ='belum') {
       $this->db->set('sudah');
   } else{
       $this->db->set('belum');
   }
   $this->db->where($where);
   $this->db->update($tb_peserta);}
```

**My View**

```
<?=anchor('admin/Ca_pendaftar/status_verifikasi/'.$tb_peserta->no_pendaftaran,
              'Konfirmasi', ['class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm' , 'onclick'=>"return confirm('Ubah status pendaftar ?');"])?>
```

Comment: set syntax should be $this->db->set('column_name','value');

Comment: You're missing an equal there $status_verifikasi ='belum'

Comment: Also what is `$status_verifikasi` ??

Comment: if :
status_verifikasi($where,$tb_peserta){
        if ($status_verifikasi ='belum') {
           $this->db->set($status_verifikasi ='sudah');
       } else{
           $this->db->set($status_verifikasi ='belum');
       }
       $this->db->where($where);
       $this->db->update($tb_peserta);
   }


**So error like that**


A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'sudah' in 'field list'

UPDATE `tb_peserta` SET `sudah` = '' WHERE `no_pendaftaran` = '13'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter `Set` syntax should be

```
$this->db->set('column_name','value');
```

Note :  Equal `=` is assignment operator . To compare you need to use `==` comparison operator

```
if ($status_verifikasi == 'belum') { .. }
```

**Update1:**

you need to check the previous value using select query like this then you need to update the status based on previous value .

```
function status_verifikasi($where,$tb_peserta){

     $this->db->select('status_verifikasi');
     $this->db->from($tb_peserta);
     $this->db->where($where);
     $result = $this->db->get()->result();

    if($result && $result[0]->status_verifikasi =='belum')
    {
       $this->db->set('status_verifikasi','sudah');
    } else{
       $this->db->set('status_verifikasi','belum');
    }

    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update($tb_peserta);
}
```

Comment: like that ? status_verifikasi($where,$tb_peserta){
        if ($status_verifikasi ='belum') {
           $this->db->set('status_verifikasi','sudah');
       } else{
           $this->db->set('status_verifikasi','belum');
       }
       $this->db->where($where);
       $this->db->update($tb_peserta);
   }

Comment: its work, for 'not yet' to 'already'
but, not work if for 'already' to 'not yet'
help please
I mean, I want to be able to change the status from not yet to already, and from already to not yet

Comment: $status_verifikasi ='belum'  use ==  @EkaWahyuSholeha

Comment: $status_verifikasi   where from you get this variable ? @EkaWahyuSholeha

Comment: $status_verifikasi is name column

Comment: you need status to update if it's 1 in db it should update 0 . vice versa is it you want ? @EkaWahyuSholeha

Comment: yes that i mean..
I'm sorry if it's hard to explain it, because I'm not fluent in english

Comment: you need to check the value and then update like this . try my update1 @EkaWahyuSholeha

Comment: glad to help you @EkaWahyuSholeha

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db->set('sudah');`

should be something like

`$this->db->set('sudah', 'value');`

There is one more issue

// you have used assignment operator instead of comparison operator

`if ($status_verifikasi ='belum') {`

should be

`if ($status_verifikasi == 'belum') {`

Comment: like that :
status_verifikasi($where,$tb_peserta){
        if ($status_verifikasi ='belum') {
           $this->db->set('status_verifikasi','sudah');
       } else{
           $this->db->set('status_verifikasi','belum');
       }
       $this->db->where($where);
       $this->db->update($tb_peserta);
   }

Comment: {status_verifikasi($where,$tb_peserta){
        if ($status_verifikasi=='belum') {
           $this->db->set('status_verifikasi','sudah');
       } else{
           $this->db->set('status_verifikasi','belum');
       }
       $this->db->where($where);
       $this->db->update($tb_peserta);
   }}

**This work**
but just one session, if i want change again, this not work :(

Comment: I can't understand, what are you trying to say?

Comment: I'm sorry if it's hard to explain it, because I'm not fluent in english..
i mean, status default is "belum" , i want change if student if students have already confirmed, the status changes to "sudah"

Comment: That should happen if you implement both the changes mentioned in my answer.